# Python PyQt5 Add List Item from another Py-File

Tags: python, pyqt5, mitmproxy

when clicking a button in the PyQt5 Ui iam starting a mitmproxy. When the proxy is started, i try to change a listWidget with Data from the Proxy.

`main.py`

```py
    import sys
    
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
    from MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow
    
    class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    
        def __init__(self, *args, obj=None, **kwargs):
            super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.setupUi(self)
    
            self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Start)
    
        def Start(self):
            x = threading.Thread(target=self.StartMITM)
            x.start()
    
        def StartMITM(self):
            os.system("mitmweb -s mitmproxy.py -q --no-web-open-browser")
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        win = MainWindow()
        win.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`mitmproxy.py` - this is the error part

```py
    from mitmproxy import http
    from main import MainWindow
    
    def response(flow):
        MainWindow.listWidget.addItem(flow.request.pretty_url)
```

Can I connect to the Widgets from another File?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has 2 independent processes: The GUI and the mitmproxy script. And communicating both processes does not imply importing modules since you would be creating another widget, also objects should not be accessed through classes (I recommend you check your basic python notes).

In this the solution is to use some Inter process communication (IPC), in this case you can use [Qt Remote Objects (QtRO)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtremoteobjects-index.html):

main.py

```py
from functools import cached_property

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtRemoteObjects, QtWidgets


class Bridge(QtCore.QObject):
    messageChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def add_message(self, message):
        self.messageChanged.emit(message)


class MitmwebManager(QtCore.QObject):
    logChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # self.process.setProcessChannelMode(QtCore.QProcess.MergedChannels)
        self.process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.handle_log)
        self.process.setProgram("mitmweb")

    @cached_property
    def process(self):
        return QtCore.QProcess()

    def start(self, arguments):
        self.process.setArguments(arguments)
        self.process.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.process.kill()

    def handle_log(self):
        data = self.process.readAllStandardOutput()
        codec = QtCore.QTextCodec.codecForName("UTF-8")
        message = codec.toUnicode(data)
        self.logChanged.emit(message)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start", checkable=True)
        self.listwidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.logview = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(readOnly=True)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        lay = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(central_widget)
        lay.addWidget(self.button, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        lay.addWidget(self.listwidget, 1, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.logview, 1, 1)

        self.register_node = QtRemoteObjects.QRemoteObjectRegistryHost(
            QtCore.QUrl("local:registry")
        )
        self.source_node = QtRemoteObjects.QRemoteObjectHost(
            QtCore.QUrl("local:replica"), QtCore.QUrl("local:registry")
        )
        self.source_node.enableRemoting(self.bridge, "bridge")

        self.button.toggled.connect(self.handle_toggled)
        self.mitmweb.logChanged.connect(self.handle_log_changed)
        self.bridge.messageChanged.connect(self.handle_message_changed)

        self.resize(640, 480)

    @cached_property
    def mitmweb(self):
        return MitmwebManager()

    @cached_property
    def bridge(self):
        return Bridge()

    def handle_toggled(self, checked):
        if checked:
            self.mitmweb.start(["-s", "script.py", "--no-web-open-browser"])
            self.button.setText("Stop")
        else:
            self.mitmweb.stop()
            self.button.setText("Start")

    def handle_log_changed(self, message):
        self.logview.insertPlainText(message)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        super().closeEvent(event)
        self.mitmweb.stop()

    def handle_message_changed(self, message):
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(message)
        self.listwidget.addItem(item)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    view = MainWindow()
    view.show()

    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**script.py**

```py
from mitmproxy import http

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtRemoteObjects


class Bridge(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, bridge, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._message = ""
        self._bridge = bridge

        self.bridge.initialized.connect(self.handle_initialized)

    @property
    def bridge(self):
        return self._bridge

    @property
    def message(self):
        return self._message

    def send_message(self, message):
        self._message = message

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def handle_initialized(self):
        self.bridge.add_message(self._message)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, QtCore.QCoreApplication.quit)


def send_qt(message):
    qt_app = QtCore.QCoreApplication([])
    replica_node = QtRemoteObjects.QRemoteObjectNode(QtCore.QUrl("local:registry"))
    replica_bridge = replica_node.acquireDynamic("bridge")
    bridge = Bridge(replica_bridge)
    bridge.send_message(message)
    qt_app.exec_()


def response(flow):
    send_qt(flow.request.pretty_url)
```